# InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: in razorpage c# app

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I am working on a web app using razor pages and c# to do surplus for the company I work for. I am using LDAP to authenticate the user's username and password and pass the user's first name and last name to a welcome message on the surplus page, but when the user logs in with a valid account I get this error when it tries to load the surplus form page:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Void OnGet(), Void OnGet(System.String, System.String)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageHandlerMethodSelector.Select(PageContext context)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: Void OnGet(), Void OnGet(System.String, System.String)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageHandlerMethodSelector.Select(PageContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

here is my loginpage cs code:

```
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
    
    namespace Surplus.Pages
    {
        public class LoginModel : PageModel
        {
            [BindProperty]
            public string Username { get; set; }
    
            [BindProperty]
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    
            public IActionResult OnPost()
            {
                if (!ValidateUser(Username, Password))
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password.";
                    return Page();
                }
    
                var user = GetUserDetailsFromLDAP(Username);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Failed to retrieve user details from Server.";
                    return Page();
                }
    
                // Pass user details to the surplus entry form
                return RedirectToPage("/SurplusEntryForm", new { firstName = user.FirstName, lastName = user.LastName });
            }
    
            private bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                    {
                        // Validate the user's credentials against the LDAP server
                        return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle any exception that occurred during the LDAP authentication
                    // Log the exception or perform error handling as per your application's requirements
                    Console.WriteLine($"LDAP authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
                }
    
                return false; // Return false if authentication fails or an error occurs
            }
    
    
            private User GetUserDetailsFromLDAP(string username)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                    {
                        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
    
                        if (userPrincipal != null)
                        {
                            var firstName = userPrincipal.GivenName;
                            var lastName = userPrincipal.Surname;
    
                            // Create and return a User object
                            return new User { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle any exception that occurred while retrieving user details from LDAP
                    // Log the exception or perform error handling as per your application's requirements
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve user details from Server: {ex.Message}");
                }
    
                return null; // Return null if the user is not found or an error occurs
            }
    
        }
    }

here is the user.cs model the login page uses:

using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.DirectoryServices;


namespace Surplus.Pages
{
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }

        public bool ValidateLDAP(string userId, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var ldapManager = new LdapManager();
                return ldapManager.Validate(userId, password);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exception that occurred during LDAP validation
                Console.WriteLine($"LDAP validation failed: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void ConnectToDatabase()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    // Perform database operations here

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any database connectivity exceptions
                Console.WriteLine($"Database connection failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        internal object GetUserDetailsFromLDAP(string username)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class LdapManager
    {
        public bool Validate(string userId, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = LdapPath();
                string username = UserFullId(userId);
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                ds.FindOne();
                return true;
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string UserFullId(string userId)
        {
            string value = string.Format(@"{0}@{1}", userId, "YourDomainName");
            return value;
        }

        private string LdapPath()
        {
            string value = string.Format(@"LDAP://{0}:{1}", "YourDomainName", 389);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the surpluspage C# code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Surplus.Pages
{
    public class SurplusEntryFormModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = "Data Source=dbname;Initial Catalog=tablename;User ID=dbusername;Password=dbpassword;";
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string WelcomeMessage { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string AssetTag { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string BulidingName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Reason { get; set; }

        public List<string> BuildingOptions { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Initialize the BuildingOptions list
            BuildingOptions = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT ID, BuildingName FROM SurplusItemsNew";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string buildingName = reader["BuildingName"].ToString();
                                BuildingOptions.Add(buildingName);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception
                // For simplicity, this example just rethrows the exception
                throw ex;
            }
        }


        public List<string> ReasonOptions { get; } = new List<string>
        {
            "Broken",
            "Burned Out",
            "Extinction",
            "No Longer Used",
            "Obsolete",
            "Other"
        };

        public void OnGet(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            WelcomeMessage = $"Welcome, {FirstName} {LastName}!";
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostSearchItem()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssetTag))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a valid Asset Tag.");
                return Page();
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT BulidingName, ItemName, Description, Reason FROM Items WHERE AssetTag = @assetTag";
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assetTag", AssetTag);

                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                BulidingName = reader["BulidingName"].ToString();
                                ItemName = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
                                Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
                                Reason = reader["Reason"].ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Item not found with the given Asset Tag.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Database connection failed: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried stepping through breakpoints googling the error and looking at my code

I am still new to razor pages and c# so any help would be amazing

thanks again for any help in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple handlers named `OnGet` in the same `PageModel` class. Parameters play no part in disambiguating between handlers based on the same HTTP method, despite the fact that the compiler will allow it. Neither does the `Async` suffix, so `OnGet()`, `OnGet(string s)` and `OnGetAsync()` are all seen as duplicates.

You could change one of the handlers to a [named handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods) instead e.g.

```
public void OnGetWelcome(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    WelcomeMessage = $"Welcome, {FirstName} {LastName}!";
}
```